# See output of command running in background

Tags: linux, unix

I was running a process in background like:

> java -jar RateUpdate.jar&

The output was showing up in the putty terminal.
However I lost ssh connection to my putty terminal and so restarted the session. I can see that the process I ran in background is still running(using ps aux|grep java)
However I want to see the output as well as I was getting before I lost connection.How can I do that .Could anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following:

> nohup java -jar RateUpdateBUS.jar>log22Julylog &

and it worked just fine.Closing the terminal didnt stop the process and output was redirected to log22Julylog file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use screen. See some examples [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/), and [here](http://shebang.brandonmintern.com/tips-for-remote-unix-work-ssh-screen-and-vnc/) some examples with ssh to solve your connections lost.

Comment: +1. I suggest adding an immediate example on how to run the command `java -jar RateUpdate.jar` with screen, and restore it after reconnecting with another ssh session.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance that you are going to need to reconnect and resume the command your best bet would be to use [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/). It is a modern remake of the older utility GNU Screen.

However if you did not know in advance and you want to save a program which is already "lost" with no terminal you can use [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) to reattach it to a terminal to get it back.